# Overlay input by div

Tags: html, css

I am developing a form and in that form there's a checkbox. If I check the checkbox then the input field before the checkbox has to hide behind an opaque div, so the user can't fill it in anymore.
But if I work with z-index the TD element changes the height.

The code:

```
<table class="prijzen">
<tr>
<td Verhuurperiode</td>
<td>Prijs</td>
<td>Geen verhuur</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="periode_naam" style="padding-bottom:2px;">Maand:</td>
 <td class="periode_prijs"><input type="Text" name="standaard_prijs_maand" maxlength="7"     
size="5" class="input_prijzen"></td>
<td class="geen_verhuur"><div id="verbergen_prijsvak"></div><div style="float:left;"><input    
type="Checkbox"></div><div class="align_checkbox">&nbsp;Huren per maand is niet   
mogelijk</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.input_prijzen{
    height:17px;
    font-size:10px;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:100;
}
#verbergen_prijsvak{
    position:relative;
    left:0px;top:0px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:red;
    filter:alpha(opacity=25);
    opacity:0.25;
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason that you just don't disable the checkbox?

Comment: Sorry, but the question is a bit hard to understand. Do you have any JavaScript that hides the input field? Why are you hiding it behind a div, wouldn't disabling the field be easier, or if you really want to get rid of it, setting visibility to none?

Comment: If you set the `disabled` property on the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input) and make the `<div>` opaque, does that do what you want?

Comment: disabling is also fine, but a also want to make the user clear that it can´t be filled in anymore, so make it an other collor.

Comment: @anydb opaque is what i need, but how to opaque the input? If i want to opaque the div it has to overlay the input because it has to stay visible a bit

Comment: You can style a disabled input field with CSS. See http://jsfiddle.net/SwLhv/ for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing what you are trying to do will not be a good practice instead try to disable the `textbox` if the `checkbox` is `checked` and enable it when `checkbox` is `unchecked`.

You can do something like this

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on("click",function(){
if($(this).attr("checked"))
$('#txtbox').attr("disabled","disabled");
else
$('#txtbox').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

**[See working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/DuNWU/)**

Comment: Works fine! Some small adjustments and it's perfect!

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.verbergen').click(function(){
  if($(this).attr("checked")){
   $('#input_1').attr("disabled","disabled");
   $('#input_1').toggleClass("input_prijzen_hide");
  } 
  else 
  {
   $('#input_1').removeAttr("disabled");
   $('#input_1').removeClass("input_prijzen_hide");
  } 
 });
});

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar Glad it helped.Pleasure mate.

Answer (score 0):

"Hiding" the text input field behind another div to stop the user from entering text is not best practice.   The best way to achieve this effect would be to use javascript to set the text input as disabled.

Here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/nsuvx/1/